# Symmetric Part of the inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

I've this question that i hope it has an elegant solution.

Consider the symmetric part of a matrix $\mathcal{H}\{A\} = \dfrac{A+A^{T}}{2}$ where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Furthermore, consider that $\mathcal{H}\{A\}<0$, i.e. is negative-definite.

Provided that $A$ is invertible: Is it possible to say that $\mathcal{H}\{A^{-1}\}$ will be also negative-definite?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain the notation $0 \not \in \sigma(A)$?

Comment: $A$ is invertible. Sorry, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the symmetric part of $A$ is negative definite, then you have
$x^t (A + A^t) x < 0 $ for all non-zero column vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, which is equivalent to $x^t A x < 0 $ for all non-zero column vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Now do a change of variables $x = A^{-1}y$, and you get that, for all non-zero column vectors $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y^t (A^{-1})^t y < 0 $, which is equivalent to saying that the symmetric part of $A^{-1}$ is negative definite.

Comment: Thanks for the early response! I'm lost in the second line... How can you say that $x^{t}Ax<0$ if $A$ is not symmetric? Thanks!

Comment: If $A$ is a real matrix,  $x^t A x$ is a real number, so its sign is well defined. It is not the case, however, if $A$ has complex entries; in this case you need $A$ to be Hermitian.